# Date Converter does not work when serializing with System.Text.Json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I'm creating a Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web Api. I have a need to serialize date without time in a Get method. I read that Asp.Net 3.1 uses System.Text.Json for serialization by default. So, I Added JsonConverter attribute to model property and added a Converter.  The Converter class using System.Text.Json does not work but the one using Json.Net work (See below code). Do I need to add anything for Converter in System.Text.Json to work?

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateConverter))]
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

**System.Text.Json**

```
public class DateConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(),
                "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        DateTime dateTimeValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(dateTimeValue.ToString(
                "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

**Json.Net**

```
Register in Startup.cs
    services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();

public class DateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use your `System.Text.Json` method to test, everything works fine and the date returned in json is in the form of "yyyy-MM-dd" .Please make sure you are using `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` to serialize  date: `string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(testDate);`

Comment: Note that in case of Json.Net, I don't need to explicitly serialize to return the model from Asp.Net Controller method. I just return the model from the controller method and serialization happens in Asp.Net core stack. My controller method signature: public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyModel>>> MyControllerGetMethod()